# @Async and @Transactional is not working together

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-transactions

I am using Spring 3.2.2 version,

I have a issue like when I am using `@Transactional` and `@Async` together its not working.

Sample Code :

In Main class:

```
@Override
@Transactional(value = "transactionManager")
public response process(inputparams) throws ReportServiceException {

    List<Future<Response>> futures=new ArrayList<Future<Response>>();

        for (Iterating for 4 times lets assume) {

            Future<Response> future =publisher.saveLogic(input);
            futures.add(future);

        }
       // After initiating threads done in above loop then
       // Iterating all futures and waiting till all threads done             


}
```

// In Publisher class :

```
@Async("reportWorkManagerTaskExecutor")
public Future<ReportResponse> saveReport(ReportSaveRequestDTO reportSaveRequestDTO){

    //save logic to db 
    return new AsyncResult<Response>(null);

}
```

// In xml file configuration like

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="reportDataSource" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<task:annotation-driven executor="reportWorkManagerTaskExecutor"/>
```

When I remove `@Async` (Thread concept) from `saveRepor`t method its working perfectly.
but when I add it not working.
I tried adding adding `@Transaction` for `saveReport` method also still no use.

Comment: The transactional resources are thread bound using `@Async` starts a new thread and as such transactions don't propagate. You should make your `@ASync` method transactional. If that doesn't work there is something missing in your tx setup.

Comment: @Deinum,  When I applied `@Transaction` to `@Async` method Its not responding anything, I added xml configuration also in question. please tell me what is wrong in transaction setup